# Worklight 7.1: Build failed due to ENABLE_BITCODE set to YES on the project.

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

/native/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.framework/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid(WLAFURLRequestSerialization.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/mobilefirst-platform-support-for-ios-9/

Updating existing apps or submitting new apps on the App Store (with Xcode7 and iOS 9 features)
Review the following sections to learn what actions you need to take so that your app can support iOS 9.

Bitcode

iOS9 introduces a new feature called bitcode, an intermediate code uploaded to the Apple App Store. Apple compiles the bitcode of the application to optimize it for each type of devices. To learn more about bitcode, see the Apple documentation.

At this time, the IBM MobileFirst Platform SDK does not support bitcode. Your application will fail to build with Xcode 7 unless you disable bitcode. If bitcode is enabled, you will see an error message.

Action required

Disable bitcode for your project: In Xcode, select Build Settings > Build Options and set Enable Bitcode to No.